# How do you set a token as an HTTPHeader for a get request in java?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I'm trying to write a test to receive a JSON response from an API and I need to set a security token in the header for the API call.  I've already verified that I am receiving a valid token from the get/token API.  When I try to execute the HttpGet I am receiving a 401 status code. 
Update: Does anyone have a complete list of authorization token types?

```
public void listAllDoctors() throws IOException {

    String listAllDoctors = "/api/doctors/search";

    HttpGet getDEV = new HttpGet(DEVBASE_ENDPOINT + listAllDoctors);
    getDEV.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "token " + TOKEN);
    getDEV.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

    response = client.execute(getDEV);

    int actualStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    assertEquals(actualStatus, 200);
}
```

Comment: We need more information.  What kind of token is the API expecting (e.g. Basic, Bearer, Digest, etc.)?  This should be documented in the the API you're using.  Also, you will likely need a space in `"token"`, i.e. `"token " + TOKEN`.  Once you know the type of token, put that in the string instead.  e.g. `"Bearer " + TOKEN`.

Comment: The API documentation says that it is of type "GUID".  I'm trying to reach out to the developer for help but not getting much response.

Comment: I figured out that the API uses a custom header token authentication. So the line of code goes like this: getDev.setHeader("token", "Token value goes here");

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the API uses a custom header token authentication. So the line of code goes like this:

```
getDev.setHeader("token", "Token value goes here");
```